# Two-pane text editor that executes external commands for preview

Tags: linux, text-editor, live-preview

When editing Markdown, reStructuredText or [dot graph files](http://www.graphviz.org/Documentation.php), I'd like to see an instant preview of the file in a second pane.

Is there a text editor for linux that is able to execute an external command whenever the text is changed, and displays the results of that command in a second pane?

Answer (score 1):

There is https://github.com/sverweij/atom-graphviz-preview-plus which adds a live-preview pane to the Atom editor, for dot graph files.

Comment: There is also an [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Stephanvs.dot) for Visual Studio Code, which is more snappy and just faster than Atom (subjectively) both on Linux and Windows where I use it.